# Getting a weird error in Cypress and unsure what's causing it?

Tags: cypress

I'm getting this error in Cypress:

```
[14884:0531/191841.692335:ERROR:system_services.cc(34)] SetApplicationIsDaemon: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "paramErr: error in user parameter list" (-50
```

Looked it up and can't find information anywhere specific to Cypress, does anyone know what's causing it?

It's not failing my tests, but it's making the build in circleci show a failure :(

Thanks,

Comment: I'm also facing this issue, test cases are passing in my co-worker's system but not in mine, so I'm still trying finding the cause but I think it's probably some version mismatch with the some package or libraries

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your config setup but if it's using the default Electron browser I   usually get this error. If i change to browser: "chrome" in cypress.run this error message disappears.